# IPv6 extremely slow on Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm running into an issue on my server where IPv6 is unbearably slow to connect (often timing out entirely).

For example, a recent `wget`:

```
--2017-10-01 20:12:49--  https://ci.somesite.net/file
Resolving ci.somesite.net (ci.somesite.net)... 2400:abcd:1234:f::1234:1234, 2401:bcde:2345:f::2345:2345, 123.45.67.89, ...
Connecting to ci.somesite.net (ci.somesite.net)|2400:abcd:1234:f::1234:1234|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ci.somesite.net (ci.somesite.net)|2401:bcde:2345:f::2345:2345|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ci.somesite.net (ci.somesite.net)|123.45.67.89|:443... connected.
```

Instead of failing on resolution (which is what I'd normally expect), the failure is on IPv6 connection instead. There is no issue with IPv4.

What is going on here, and what can I do to resolve this issue?

---

The server is running latest Ubuntu 16.04.

Relevant `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff  
          inet addr:123.98.76.54  Bcast:123.98.76.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2607:abcd:ef1:2345::/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::ec4:aabb:ccdd:eeff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:574132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:317319 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:659730231 (659.7 MB)  TX bytes:23334546 (23.3 MB)
```

Comment: Those IPv6 addresses look fake. Did you modify the output or is your network admin providing you with fake addresses and DNS answers?

Comment: I did redact sensitive information. My IPv6 address is real and I am getting real answers.